# unexpected tab-switch in <p:tabMenu> on AJAX request after validation failure

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, mojarra

I'm using PrimeFaces' [`<p:tabMenu>`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/tabMenu.xhtml)  along with input components with validation. Whenever a validation failure occurs for such input components, a tab-switch is not possible (which is intended behavior). However, when I change the input that caused the validation failure, the subsequent AJAX-request causes the active tab to change.

I managed to reproduce the behavior in a very simple example:

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="tab" value="#{bean.activeTab}" />
</f:metadata>

<h:form id="theForm">
  <p:tabMenu id="menu" activeIndex="#{bean.activeTab}">
    <p:menuitem id="tab0" update="menu content" value="Tab 0">
      <f:param name="tab" value="0"/>
    </p:menuitem>
    <p:menuitem id="tab1" update="menu content" value="Tab 1">
      <f:param name="tab" value="1"/>
    </p:menuitem>
  </p:tabMenu>

  <h:panelGroup id="content">
    <p>Active Tab: #{bean.activeTab}<br/></p>

    <h:inputText id="someInput" value="#{bean.someInput}" required="true">
      <p:ajax update="menu content"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <p:message id="m_someInput" for="someInput"/>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

The backing-bean to the view is `@ViewScoped` and contains only getters and setters for the following properties:

```
private String someInput = null;
private Integer activeTab = 0;
```

Run the example, try to switch to "Tab 1", which fails due to the empty `someInput` field and shows a validation failure. Input some text into the input field and click outside the input to trigger the change event and the AJAX request. Now the second tab ("Tab 1") gets active! Why? Is this a bug in PrimeFaces or am I doing something wrong?

My environment:

- PrimeFaces 7.0/8.0
- JSF 2.2.15/2.3.17 (Mojarra)
- Wildfly 10.1.0.Final/26.0.1.Final

### Update

- I've created an issue at github [<s>#4471</s>](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4771) with a reproducer project, which is now closed.
- The issue only exists with Mojarra, even with 2.3.17. MyFaces seems to work as expected.
- The real cause is probably Mojarra [issue #4562](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4562).

### Workaround

A workaround, that might or might not be suitable, depending on your actual needs, is to turn the tab-switch AJAX request into a non AJAX POST request by adding `ajax="false"` to the `<p:menuItem>` tags.

Comment: Does adding `resetValues="true"` to the `p:ajax` help?

Comment: No, adding `resetValues="true"` has no effect here.